# typescript overloading class methods - same return type, different parameters

Tags: typescript

I've got a typescript class:

```
class ContactModel {

    public getUsage(type: string): restangular.IElement {
      return this.getBase().one('usages', type);
    }

    public getUsage(customerId: number, type: string): restangular.IElement {
      return this.ModelFactory.createRequestMapper(ContactModel.options)
        .one('customers', customerId).all('contacts/usages', type);
    }

    //...
}
```

which causes the compiler to throw following error:

```
>> app/modules/common/model/ContactModel.ts(27,12): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
>> app/modules/common/model/ContactModel.ts(31,12): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
```

The only difference I see between this example and the [TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-overloads) is that their examples have different return types and I've got the same return types (both cases have different input parameters).

The question is: what am I doing wrong - or do typescript class methods need to have different method argument types to allow overloading? That seems stupid, since both .Net and Java support overloading with same return types and different input types.

Comment: it would probably be better, to put the customerId argument as an optional parameter at the end of your getUsage, and keep only one public `getUsage` method, internally you could then check if the customerId has the default value and if not, use it in your function call. ps, your comment about .net and java is not relevant as it gets compiled in javascript and there it is unknown

Comment: @Icepickle thanks for your comment. My counter-comment: [1] my question is not what I can do (to make the code compile) but it's about what is allowed in TS and what is not - or what is the compile error cause, [2] the comment **is** relevant, because it's relates to the **syntax of a language** and it doesn't matter whether something is transpiled to something else or not. I'm pretty sure it is possible to modify TS to allow that feature. *Overloading* is something known from C, C++, C#, Java. And different input parameters are good enough to use overloading there.

Comment: well, sure, for a language that knows how to use overloading, how would you translate such a direct statement to javascript? In javascript there is (except for the arguments) no direct access, to your method signature and how you call it (though TypeScript might be able to do it, they should then also do the extra logic to differentiate based on argument count, which doesn't sound very secure to me)

Comment: @Icepickle in that case it should be called *quasi-overloading* instead of *overloading* to emphasise, that it is different from the normal pattern of overloading methods, which people are used to - that's my opinion :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53351061/why-typescript-doesnt-support-function-overloading-in-a-right-way

Answer (score 49, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't do runtime type information, so you have to do overload disambiguation yourself. Note that in the example in the Handbook, there's only one function implementation, whereas you have two.

```
class ContactModel {
  public getUsage(type: string): restangular.IElement;
  public getUsage(customerId: number, type: string): restangular.IElement;
  public getUsage(typeOrCustomerId: string|number, type?: string): restangular.IElement {
    if (typeof typeOrCustomerId === 'string') {
      // First overload
      return this.getBase().one('usages', type);
    } else {
      // Second overload
      return this.ModelFactory.createRequestMapper(ContactModel.options)
        .one('customers', customerId).all('contacts/usages', type);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Clear explanation. the first two methods have just declared the parameters and not implemented.