# typescript overload considers only one of the overloaded signatures

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to apply typescript's method overloading on a class method, for the filter class method.

```
class Vector<T> {
    static of<T>(vals: T[]): Vector<T> {
        return undefined;
    }
    // filter<U extends T>(fn:(x:T)=>x is U): Vector<U>;
    filter(fn:(x:T)=>boolean): this {
        return undefined;
    }
}

const v1 = Vector.of([1,2,3]).filter(x=>x>1);
```

This works fine, until the commented line is uncommented.

When uncommenting that line, we get the error:

```
ttt.ts(12,38): error TS2345: Argument of type '(x: number) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(x: number) => x is number'.
  Signature '(x: number): boolean' must be a type predicate.
```

So it seems typescript (2.7.2) ignores the overload and picks only one of the type definitions for `filter`, which I don't understand. This pattern of having the overloaded `filter` is relatively known, and [used by typescript's own es5.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7b9ceb85fa4e19ade740faa2af2e00e62e16f7c9/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1067-L1078), in addition overloading [is also supported for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31815015/516188) so I would expect it to be supported also in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that for functions with an implementation, the last signature is the implementation signature and is not publicly available:

```
class Vector<T> {
    static of<T>(vals: T[]): Vector<T> {
        return undefined;
    }
    filter<U extends T>(fn:(x:T)=>x is U): Vector<U>;
    filter(fn:(x:T)=>boolean): this 
    // Private signature 
    filter(fn:(x:T)=>boolean): this {
        return undefined;
    }
}
const v1 = Vector.of([1,2,3]).filter(x=>x>1);
const v2 = Vector.of([1,2,3, ""]).filter((x) : x is string =>typeof x === "string");
```